# Get path of the image and load it with BufferedImage

Tags: java, filepath, image-loading

I don't know why in Java it should be so complicated, but I've already spent a good few hours on this. I have a png image in \src\resources\resize-cursor.png

Now, I want to use this image with `BufferedImage` class

```
BufferedImage myPicture = null;

try {
    // this is just one of the examples I tried... I've already tried like 10 ways to achieve this but I am always getting NullReferenceException
    myPicture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("\\resources\\resize-cursor.png")));
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a one working way just to link the png resource in my app?

Comment: It looks like the slash orientation is in the opposite direction.  Try doing this: `"/resources/resize-cursor.png"`.  I don't know if this will work, which is why I'm leaving it as a comment.  When I've loaded in assets through `getResourceAsStream`, this is how I've always done it.

Comment: Did you try myPicture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resize-cursor.png"))) ?

Comment: The JavaDoc is pretty explicit on that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String) , so I guess rayryeng is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/resize-cursor.png")`?

Answer (score 0):

Open the jar with 7zip or you maybe can open it in the IDE.

Then search the file. My guess: /resources is the top directory.

```
myPicture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resize-cursor.png")));
```

Use slash `/` for a case-sensitive path.

Make sure that the class of `getClass()` is in the same jar. Think what inheritance might do.
You can do too:

```
myPicture = ImageIO.read(ClassInJar.class.getResourceAsStream("/resize-cursor.png")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using 2 slashes and they are the wrong way. Use this "/" instead of "\" or "\". Also it may help if you have made your resource folder a class folder.

Here are 2 links if you like some more information:
1. [Oracle tutorial on BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)
2. [Documentation of BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

The way i like to load images is to make a class to make it more simple like this.

```
public class BufferedImageLoader {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImages(String path) {
        try { image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path)); } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return image;
    }

}
```

And to load a "bufferedImage" using this.

```
BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
image1 = loader.loadImages("/image1.png");
image2 = loader.loadImages("/image2.png");
```